# Having trouble sending email xampp in windows 10

Tags: php, email, xampp, phpmailer, windows-10

I am looking for help to send email with xampp (for test).

I did some code and I got this result in chrome:

```
SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 mx.google.com ESMTP j5sm1968029vdy.0 - gsmtp
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-mx.google.com at your service, [190.131.48.40]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection j5sm1968029vdy.0 - gsmtp
SMTP connect() failed.
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

My code is this:

```
                <?php
            /**
             * This example shows settings to use when sending via Google's Gmail servers.
             */

            //SMTP needs accurate times, and the PHP time zone MUST be set
            //This should be done in your php.ini, but this is how to do it if you don't have access to that
            //date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

            require 'PHPMailer-master/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

            $mail = new PHPMailer;

            //Create a new PHPMailer instance
            //$mail = new PHPMailer;

            //Tell PHPMailer to use SMTP
            $mail->isSMTP();

            //Enable SMTP debugging
            // 0 = off (for production use)
            // 1 = client messages
            // 2 = client and server messages
            $mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

            //Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
            $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

            //Set the hostname of the mail server
            //Solo si ssl port 465
            //$mail->Host = 'aspmx.l.google.com';

            //Solo si TSL port 25
            $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';

            //Set the SMTP port number - 587 for authenticated TLS, a.k.a. RFC4409 SMTP submission
            $mail->Port = 587;

            //Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
            $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tsl';

            //Whether to use SMTP authentication
            $mail->SMTPAuth = true;

            //Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
            $mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com";

            //Password to use for SMTP authentication
            $mail->Password = "mypassword";

            //Set who the message is to be sent from
            $mail->setFrom('adtecDo@gmail.com', 'Pagina Web');

            //Set an alternative reply-to address
            //$mail->addReplyTo('replyto@example.com', 'First Last');

            //Set who the message is to be sent to
            $mail->addAddress('davisgarces@gmail.com', 'Davis Garces');

            //Set the subject line
            $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
            $mail->Body = 'This is a test sent from my own pc';

            //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
            //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
            //$mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('contents.html'), dirname(__FILE__));

            //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
            $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

            //Attach an image file
            //$mail->addAttachment('images/phpmailer_mini.png');

            //send the message, check for errors
            if (!$mail->send()) {
                echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
            } else {
                echo "Message sent!";
            }

            ?>
```

I have a windows 10 tech preview OS. I am using xampp without Mercury. I download PHPMailer and I am using it as well. I already tried the php.ini and sendmail.ini configuration and NOTHING HAD WORKING!

I hope anyone could help me!

Thanks.

Comment: Try setting `SMTPDebug = 4` - it will give you lower-level info on the connection.

Comment: Hi @Synchro. I did what you said and I got the same error just with a lot more lines. There is a line that I thinks is the error:
CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
Maybe I can't link to the correct web page? gmail? I don't have a clue.

Comment: You have a typo in your code: `tsl` should be `tls` for `SMTPSecure`.